# why are 2 different devices prepending 1 in Call Log differently?

Tags: android

i have 2 devices

1. Samsung SGH-T830, running 2.2
2. Motorola Droid Razr M, running 4.4.2

the CallLog on the Samsung prepends a 1 to all incoming phone numbers calling the device.

the CallLog on the Droid does not.

is this behavior dependent on the OS version?  i was hoping it would be consistent between devices.  is there a programmatic way to force one behavior or the other?

i would like to avoid modifying my code to search for both 1xxxyyyzzzz and xxxyyyzzzz

Answer (score 1):

> is this behavior dependent on the OS version?

It is more that the behavior is up to other developers, not you. That includes device manufacturers that replace the dialer with their own code, third-party VOIP clients that add records to the `CallLog`, etc. It might also vary by OS version, though I'm a bit skeptical on that point.

> is there a programmatic way to force one behavior or the other?

Not in general. I can't rule out some devices having some means of controlling this behavior for their own dialers, or VOIP clients having some sort of API to allow third parties to control this. However, I would be surprised if any offer it, let alone all of them.

> i would like to avoid modifying my code to search for both 1xxxyyyzzzz and xxxyyyzzzz

Don't forget punctuation. Looking at the call log rendered in the dialer UI of my Nexus 4 -- where I have both mobile calls and VOIP calls -- I am seeing all sorts of formatted values, including `+` signs sometimes in front of the `1` for US calls when the device is not in the US, parentheses around US area codes, hyphens between segments of the phone number, etc.

Comment: i'm talking about how they are stored in in the column given by CallLog.Calls.NUMBER

when i access this column programmatically on either of my devices i am consistently getting unformatted numbers back as 1xxxyyyzzzz or xxxyyyzzzz.

the Samsung's dialer UI displays 1xxxyyyzzzz while the Droid's dialer displays (xxx) yyy-zzzz so i think that may be dialer dependent

Comment: @user1126515: "on either of my devices i am consistently getting unformatted numbers" -- there are thousands of device models, with hundreds of dialer implementations, in addition to all of the VOIP clients. Do not assume they will all insert data into the `CALL_LOG` the same way.